# Detecting whether or not a word file contains a duplicate

Tags: java, duplicates, hashset

I am trying to write code that will read a file and detect if the file has duplicates.

This is the code I currently have. It detects the duplicates but the output isn't what I want it do be. I want it to only output once.

```
set<String> set = new Hashset<>();
ArrayList<String>list = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner infile = new Scanner(new File args[0]));
while(infile.hasNext()){
     list.add(infile.next());
}
infile.close();


for(String word : list){
   if(set.add(word) == false){
       System.out.println("NOT UNIQUE");
   }else {
       System.out.println("UNIQUE");
   }
 }
```

Clarification on output.

I want the output to be just `UNIQUE` or `NOT UNIQUE` based on whether or not a duplicate exists.

Comment: _"the output isn't what I want it do be. However I want it to only output once."_ Please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want it to print once then use a boolean variable to store the result and then print it afterwards.

e.g.

```
boolean isUnique = true;
for(String word : list){
    if(set.add(word) == false){
       isUnique = false;
       // can break;
       break
    }
 }

 System.out.println ("isUnique: " + isUnique);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option here would be to use a `HashMap` instead of a list.  If you encounter a duplicate you can immediately stop iterating over the file:

```
Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
boolean isUnique = true;
Scanner infile = new Scanner(new File args[0]));
while (infile.hasNext()) {
    String next = infile.next();
    if (map.get(next) != null) {
        isUnique = false;
        break;
    }
    map.put(next, true);
}
if (isUnique) {
    System.out.println("UNIQUE");
}
else {
    System.out.println("NOT UNIQUE");
}
infile.close();
```